# Fetching current user likes in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm working on an application where we have integrated FB like button. Currently there is an requirement wherein we have show up all the stuffs what the current user has liked. Went through Graph API but was of no luck.

Could someone please let me know how to go about it. I just need all the likes for the current user.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Returning the `likes` of a user is easy and clearly documented in the [`user`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) object (likes connection).

But I don't think that you can get the user's likes for external websites links.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get user likes/interests, you will have to revoke user permission using FBLogin function.